# Executing a task within script every x days/months/years, depending on db value

Tags: php, mysql, cron

)

got a question. I want users to be able to enter every how many hours/days/months/years a script shall be executed.

Therefore the users enter two values - the amount (1-24) and the unit (hours, days, months, years).

The script file is being executed by a cron job every 5 mins. Within this script, a filter should check only allow the user script to run in the interval as defined.

Available variables:

- Amount (1-24)
- Unit (Hours, Days, Months, Years)
- Script start time

Does anybody have a smart approach for that? The timing should be relatively exact, close as 5 mins to the intervall. (5 mins because of possible cron job delay). So if user says every 2 hours, and starts at 2.12 pm, it should run at 4.12, 6.12 etc.

I think what I need is just the PHP code to flexible add the set interval to the start time, or last time the script has been executed.

Thanks!!!

My try:

```
    $currentDate = strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
    $dateCreated = strtotime( "2015-12-01 12:16:50" ); // i.e.
    $lastTimeExecuted = strtotime( "2015-12-02 12:16:50" ); // i.e.
    $interval = (1000*60*60)*2; // 2 Hours as timestamp

    if( $lastTimeExecuted > $dateCreated ){

        if( currentDate > ($lastTimeExecuted+$interval) ){
            // Execute Now
        }

    }else{
        // Execute Now, has never been running before
    }
```

Comment: have your written anything, we help with code, not project scopes

Comment: @Dagon just added my approach, Would that work?

Comment: the answer to that question is "did it"?

Comment: looks good except your math is a little funky. 2 hours is (60*60*2). You have (1000*60*60)*2, which is 2 thousand hours.

Comment: @Pamblam haha thats true - sorry... im working a lot with jquery and the conversion never left me ;D

Answer (score 1):

You have a cron job that runs every 5 minutes. It should execute a PHP script that queries the database, searches for scheduled jobs, executes them, and updates the time that they were last run.  Each job in the database has a field for the last time it was run. The last-run time is compared to the current time to find the elapsed time, and if the elapsed time is greater than the frequency (another field), the PHP script executes an appropriate command via `system`, `exec`, or `shell_exec`.

The script will look something like this:

```
<?php
    $link=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM jobs";
    $res=$link->query($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $elapsedTime=$date()-strtotime($row['last_run']);
        if($elapsedTime >= $row['frequency']){
            system($row['command']);
            $sql="UPDATE jobs SET last_run='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    }
?>
```

Keep in mind that frequency is in seconds.

Comment: i feel like `system()` is kind of a poor choice for a cron job unless you're going to do an output buffer.. honestly unless you're just using it to call another script then i'd maybe just use PHP.. other than that, exactly how I would have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this should be the running version:

```
    // If Job is recurring
    if( $jobRecurring == 1 ){

        $currentDateStr = strtotime( $currentDate ); // i.e. "2015-12-01 12:16:50"
        $dateCreated = strtotime( $jobStartDate ); // i.e. "2015-12-01 12:16:50"
        $lastTimeExecuted = strtotime( $jobLastRunDate ); // i.e. "2015-12-01 12:16:50"
        $jobRecurringUnit; // i.e. "Hours"
        $jobRecurringCalc;
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Minutes" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60;
        }
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Hours" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60*60;
        }
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Days" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60*60*24;
        }
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Weeks" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60*60*24*7;
        }
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Months" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60*60*24*7*30;
        }
        if( $jobRecurringUnit == "Years" ){
            $jobRecurringCalc = 60*60*24*7*365;
        }
        $interval = $jobRecurringCalc * $jobRecurringAmount;

            if( $lastTimeExecuted < $dateCreated || $currentDateStr > ($lastTimeExecuted+$interval) ){

                 // Execute Now
            }

    }
```